# Send data from one tab to another cross domain

Tags: javascript, cross-domain

Need to find the solution for the below scenario.

On click on a button, a new window of **different domain** will open in a new tab. I want to send some data from the initial window to this new window.

Solution Tried: Sending data using window.postMessage from initial tab and trying to listen to that message event on a new window. Somehow not able to listen to that event.

```
--- On click of a button
 const windowObjectReference = window.open('http://localhost:7000/elmo/experiment');
  windowObjectReference.postMessage('message data');

--- On listener side
 window.addEventListener('message', (e) {
   console.log('*********************** data', e.data);
 }, false);
```

Expectation:

1. What's the problem with the above-tried approach.
2. If it's not possible by the above approach, how to do this?

Comment: @CherryDT Added the code block

Comment: 1) You forgot the `targetOrigin` argument, please check the [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage) again. 2) I assume the target page isn't loaded yet when you send the message, so it goes nowhere. I suggest having the second page send a message to the first page when it's ready, and only then sending the main message from the first to the second page.

Comment: @CherryDT Your suggestion of handshaking worked, thanks